# tokens and coins based on ETH

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I intend to trade tokens and coins using MyEtherWallet. Is it possible to use MEW to do Tx's between ALL coins and tokens, or is the wallet limit to a specific list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for all tokens.

For coins based on ETH you need to change the network you are on which is possible in the menu at the top right of MEW. That might take a little more in-depth knowledge about that network than you want / know so I would recommend a native wallet when possible for other coins.